# An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Function () does not exist") in "COTerminalBundle.html.twig"

Tags: symfony, twig

I've recently updated my Symfony Project from 2.4 to 2.8 and now 3.4.

I'm getting that error after logging in and redirecting to the next page.

Here are the stack traces

```
ReflectionException:
Function () does not exist

  at vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Expression\Call.php:288
  at ReflectionFunction->__construct('')
     (vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Expression\Call.php:288)
  at Twig_Node_Expression_Call->reflectCallable(null)
     (vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Expression\Call.php:23)
  at Twig_Node_Expression_Call->compileCallable(object(Twig_Compiler))
     (vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Expression\Function.php:35)
  at Twig_Node_Expression_Function->compile(object(Twig_Compiler))
     (vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Compiler.php:84)
  at Twig_Compiler->subcompile(object(Twig_Node_Expression_Function))
     (vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Expression\Call.php:87)
  at Twig_Node_Expression_Call->compileArguments(object(Twig_Compiler))
     (vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Expression\Call.php:47)
  at Twig_Node_Expression_Call->compileCallable(object(Twig_Compiler))
     (vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Expression\Filter.php:32)
  at Twig_Node_Expression_Filter->compile(object(Twig_Compiler))
     (vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Compiler.php:84)
  at Twig_Compiler->subcompile(object(Twig_Node_Expression_Filter))
     (vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Print.php:30)
  at Twig_Node_Print->compile(object(Twig_Compiler))
     (vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node.php:82)
  at Twig_Node->compile(object(Twig_Compiler))
     (vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node.php:82)
  at Twig_Node->compile(object(Twig_Compiler))
     (vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Compiler.php:84)
  at Twig_Compiler->subcompile(object(Twig_Node_Body))
     (vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Module.php:303)
  at Twig_Node_Module->compileDisplay(object(Twig_Compiler))
     (vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Module.php:87)
  at Twig_Node_Module->compileTemplate(object(Twig_Compiler))
     (vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Node\Module.php:68)
  at Twig_Node_Module->compile(object(Twig_Compiler))
     (vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Compiler.php:73)
  at Twig_Compiler->compile(object(Twig_Node_Module))
     (vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php:552)
  at Twig_Environment->compile(object(Twig_Node_Module))
     (vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php:565)
  at Twig_Environment->compileSource(object(Twig_Source))
     (vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php:368)
  at Twig_Environment->loadTemplate('COTerminalBundle:Layout:default.html.twig', null)
     (vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Template.php:330)
  at Twig_Template->loadTemplate('COTerminalBundle:Layout:default.html.twig', 'COTerminalBundle:Summary:index.html.twig', 1)
     (var\cache\dev\twig\97\978d5147bd01293cb764603fc7cd00b1c51d7a1412daae1c1f3c3d008dc092ac.php:15)
  at __TwigTemplate_fc502452fd2cc771596800db9a055ed5aabb58f726f1c6aa2d28ccc6e1d17e2b->__construct(object(Twig_Environment))
     (vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php:397)
  at Twig_Environment->loadTemplate('COTerminalBundle:Summary:index.html.twig')
     (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine.php:125)
  at Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine->load('COTerminalBundle:Summary:index.html.twig')
     (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine.php:49)
  at Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine->render('COTerminalBundle:Summary:index.html.twig', array('quotes' => object(SlidingPagination), 'form' => object(FormView), 'fromDateFormatted' => null, 'toDateFormatted' => null, 'quoteLinksEnabled' => true, 'takeoffLinksEnabled' => true))
     (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine.php:45)
  at Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine->render('COTerminalBundle:Summary:index.html.twig', array('quotes' => object(SlidingPagination), 'form' => object(FormView), 'fromDateFormatted' => null, 'toDateFormatted' => null, 'quoteLinksEnabled' => true, 'takeoffLinksEnabled' => true))
     (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerTrait.php:284)
  at Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller->render('COTerminalBundle:Summary:index.html.twig', array('quotes' => object(SlidingPagination), 'form' => object(FormView), 'fromDateFormatted' => null, 'toDateFormatted' => null, 'quoteLinksEnabled' => true, 'takeoffLinksEnabled' => true))
     (src\CO\TerminalBundle\Controller\SummaryController.php:73)
  at CO\TerminalBundle\Controller\SummaryController->indexAction(object(Request))
     (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php:151)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php:68)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php:200)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (public\app_dev.php:24)
  at require('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\terminal\\public\\app_dev.php')
     (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\Resources\router.php:42)
```

When I traced it back, the variable $callable became null. I'm not sure if it's on twig or on symfony, the error.

Edit:

Here's my default.html.twig

```
{{ checkUserPageAccess() }}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <title>{% block title %}SAMSS{% endblock %}</title>
    {% include 'COTerminalBundle:Layout:fullIncludes.html.twig' %}

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class='row'>
        <div class='twelve columns'>
            <header>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='two columns'>
                        <img src='{{ asset('bundles/coterminal/images/samss/landscape.png') }}' />
                    </div>
                    <div class='two columns'>
                        <h1 class='location-header'>{{ local_name }}</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class='five columns'>
                        <div class='header-search-div'>
                            {% if checkUserAccess('takeofflist') %}
                                <a class='button radius small' href="{{ path('COTerminal_Takeoff_New') }}">Takeoff</a>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if checkUserAccess('quotelist/quotes') %}
                                <a class='button radius small' href="{{ path('COTerminal_Quote_New') }}">Quote</a>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if checkUserAccess('salesorders/salesorder') %}
                                <a class='button blue radius small' href="{{ path('COTerminalBundle_SalesOrder_New') }}">Sales Order</a>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if checkUserAccess('projectlist') %}
                                <a class='button blue radius small' href="{{ path('COTerminal_Project_New') }}">Project</a>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if checkUserAccess('salesorders/salesorder') %}
                                <a class='button yellow radius small' href="{{ path('COTerminalBundle_SalesOrder_NewStockOrder') }}">Stock Order</a>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='three columns'>
                        {% include 'COTerminalBundle:Layout:logoutPanel.html.twig' %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>

            <div class='row'>
                <div class='twelve columns'>

                    {{ knp_menu_render('main', {'currentClass':'active'}) }}

                    {% block body %}

                    {% endblock %}

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).foundationAccordion();
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like it happened when loading `COTerminalBundle:Layout:default.html.twig`. Could you maybe add the template to your question?

Comment: @dbrumann I've updated and added the template

Comment: Try removing `{{ checkUserPageAccess() }}`

Comment: I did that but the same error is displaying. (Also, I need that in order to check the accessibility of a page for each user.)

Comment: Please run `bin/console debug:twig`. It will produce quite a lot of output. Could you check if the functions `checkUserPageAccess()` and `checkUserAccess()` are listed in there?

Comment: Also, are you sure it's supposed to be `{{ checkUserPageAccess() }}` and not `{% checkUserPageAccess() %}`? From the name I would suggest that it does not create any output.

Comment: Yes, they're both there

Comment: I'll check that one.

Edit:
Yes, it is {{ checkUserPageAccess() }}

Comment: U'd actually place the logic the authorisation of an user in a middleware. A template itself should not be bothered wheter it's viewable or not. @dbrumann It would actualy would be `{% do checkUserPageAccess() %}`

Comment: @jed U have debug enabled inside `twig` as well?

Comment: Can you show the code of your Twig extension defining the `checkUserPageAccess()` function?